# How to use jq to merge files as json where the filename is the property selector and the file contents is the value?

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

I am using jq to do some json manipulation. The scenario is that I have a json file and a number of other files that contain either json or strings, and I want to merge them into a single output.

**main.json** contains:

```
{
  "property1": "someValue",
  "sub": {
     "property2": "property2"
   }
}
```

**.property1** (this is the filename) contains:

```
newValue
```

**.sub.property2** (this is the filename) contains:

```
newProperty2
```

**.other** (this is the filename) contains:

```
{
  "complex": {
    "cprop": "cpropvalue"
  }
}
```

I want to merge these files together, using the filename as the jq selector and the contents of the file as the value. The output of this would be:

```
{
  "property1": "newValue",
  "sub": {
     "property2": "newProperty2"
   },
   "other": {
      "complex": {
        "cprop": "cpropvalue"
      }
   }
}
```

The use case is that I have a number of key/value pairs (e.g., env vars) that I want to merge in a generic way to a json config file.

The jq tool is very powerful, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. If the last scenario (contents of file is json) isn't possible the first two are still extremely useful. Based on other searches, I think all the parts are there (filename, inputs, etc), but I'm figuring out how to combine them.

Comment: how will you distinguish between files which contain raw unwrapped strings and files which contain json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution to the closely-related problem which assumes that all the files contain valid JSON:

```
jq '
  def props: 
    split(".") | map(select(length>0));

  reduce inputs as $json (.;
    setpath(input_filename | props; $json) )
' main.json .other .property1 .sub.property2
```

The dot-files can be listed in any order (e.g. perhaps by `.???*`), but must be specified after main.json.

The main subtlety here is that the first `.` that appears after `reduce` will be populated by the contents of `main.json`.

To use the above approach to solve the problem as stated, one would need to convert the raw text in the files named .property1 and .sub.property2 to valid JSON.  This could be done in a preprocessing step, e.g. as follows:

```
jq -R .property1 | sponge .property1
jq -R .sub.property2 | sponge .sub.property2
```

Feel free to pick any of the many other alternatives and variants :-)